# Creating custom query in spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring, repository, spring-data

How to create custom query in spring for getting all user who follow me from database..this is my repository

```
@Repository
public interface FollowRepository extends JpaRepository<Follow, Long> {
    @Query("Select f from Follow f where f.user = :user and f.status = 'follow'")
    List<Follow> findByUser (@Param("user") User user);
}
```

and this is my table in database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `follow`(
    `id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` BIGINT,
    `follower_id` BIGINT,
    `status` ENUM ('follow','blocked') NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES `user`(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (follower_id) REFERENCES `user`(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: How could we know? HQL works with entities, their fields, and their associations. We have no idea of what your entities are, since you didnt post them. Your table is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Your query looks fine as far as we can tell (without knowing your entity). So what is not working about it?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("Select f from Follow f where f.userId = ?1 and f.status = ?2")
List<Follow> findByUser (Integer userId, String status);
```

You could also:

```
List<Follow> findByUserAndStatus(User user, String status);
```

EDIT: Having your status as an ENUM in your table can make it stressful when making new enums. I'd prefer having the status column as a VARCHAR and in your entity your getter for that field can be:

```
@Basic
@Column(name = "status")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public StatusEnum getStatus(){ return this.getStatus; }
```